# Expo React Native execute function when entering view

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, use-effect

I'm trying to make a function execute when a view is in foreground, but just once not on each update of the component. If the user navigates to another view and goes back to the first view it should execute that function again, but just once. Is there a solution to this?

if using useEffect without second parameter it executes on each update, if I add [] as second parameter it only executes the first time the view is rendered but not when navigating back to it.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) you can do this by listen on screen focus see [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/)

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: Thanks, had to do some minor tweaks since the react-navigation used is 3.11, but the answer works perfectly!